# Java - Accessing Scanner methods

Tags: java

Hi and hope someone can help. I'm doing a short Java course and need to set up 3 classes that basically communicate between each other but I'm failing.

You'll spot from the code below that I'm trying to split the tasks of reading user's input and doing whatever maths is required into different classes but something's wrong

Any ideas? Thanks for your interest.

Here's the simple Main class:-

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Calculator calculator = new Calculator();
    calculator.start();
}
}
```

The Calculator class (or part of it):-

```
public class Calculator {

private Reader reader;

public void Calculator(Reader reader) {
    this.reader = reader;
    System.out.println("Calculator set up.");
}

public void start() {
    while (true) {
        System.out.print("command: ");
        String command = reader.readString(); // It fails here:
        if (command.equals("end")) {
            break;
        }

        if (command.equals("sum")) {
            sum();
        } else if (command.equals("difference")) {
            difference();
        } else if (command.equals("product")) {
            product();
        }
    }
```

And finally the Reader class:-

```
public class Reader {

private Scanner input;

public void Reader(Scanner input) {
    this.input = input;
    System.out.println("Reader set up.");
}

public String readString() {
    return input.nextLine();
}

public int readInteger() {
    return Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an issue with all the constructors you are using. Constructors are special methods with *no* return type, so in your case, `public void Calculator(Reader reader)` needs to be `public Calculator(Reader reader)` (remove `void`). The same applies to the other constructors.

Once you do that, you would need to make amendments on how you are instantiating your `Calculator` class:

```
Calculator calculator = new Calculator();
```

Should become:

```
Calculator calculator = new Calculator(new Reader(new Scanner(System.in)));
```

Comment: Thanks everyone. As soon as I posted this Q the fire alarm went off so I've been outside for an hour. I've marked the accept here but all your suggestions were very helpful. I've now got it working. My thanks.

Answer (score 1):

provide constructor not mothod.

```
 Calculator(Reader reader) {
    this.reader = reader;
    System.out.println("Calculator set up.");
}
```

after that you can change your main method with @subhrajyoti suggested.

Answer (score 1):

apart from above suggestion ,
1> your constructors (Reader and Calculator) is returning void. But constructor cannot return any value. So, remove void keyword.
you have to import Scanner class (i.e. java.util.scanner).